# How to disable autoescape in django feeds?

Tags: django, feed

I use django feed framework to organize rss feeds for my website.
I need to put some hyperlinks to feed items, but al of them are
autoescaped ( "<" is replaced with "&lt;" and so on).
Is it possible to keep tags in my feed (as I understand, I can't use
{% autoescape off %} tag in feed templates)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read up on [Automatic HTML escaping in Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping) and try the following syntax. Where data is the variable which holds your link

```
{{ data|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

As jitter mentioned you can use "safe" filter, but it's annoying if you want to disable autoescaping often. Django also supports {% autoescape off %} {% autoescape end %} blocks, everything inside is block won't be autoescaped.

**EDITED:** Sorry, I haven't read your question completely only title :). Why you can't use autoescape tag in feeds? There's no restriction about it.

Comment: giolekva, I've tried it and there is atill autoescaping. 
I have an idea, that, probably, not all tags are allowed in feed templates.

Comment: There's no difference between templates, they can generate any format: HTML, XML, JSON and so on. I think you have different problem. Can you post error Django generates?

Comment: Had to use {% endautoescape %} when I tried it. Otherwise, it gave a nonsensical error about the argument needing to be either 'on' or 'off', which it was. Version: Django 1.8.0 alpha